# SSO Authentication - The oauth state was missing or invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, single-sign-on, cloud-foundry

I am trying to implement SSO Authentication in ASP.Net Core 3.1 and deploy in Pivot Cloud Foundry(PCF).

In local it's working fine but after deployment getting below error

****An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
Exception: The oauth state was missing or invalid.
Unknown location
Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()****

HomeController.cs

```
#if !LOCALTEST
        [Authorize]
#endif
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            string user = "";
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                user = User.Identity.Name;
            }
            else
            {

                // WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent
                user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Substring(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);
            }
            TempData["user"] = user;
            
            return View();
        }
```

Manifest.yml

```
---
applications:
- name: ApplicationName
  memory: 1G
  stack: cflinuxfs3
  buildpacks:
    - dicf_dotnet_core_buildpack_2339_cflinuxfs3
  instances: 2
  disk_quota: 1G
  
  env:
     ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
     GRANT_TYPE: authorization_code
     SSO_IDENTITY_PROVIDERS : XXX-sso
     SSO_SCOPES : openid,roles,user_attributes
     SSO_AUTO_APPROVED_SCOPES : openid,roles,user_attributes
     SSO_USERINFO_URL : https://appsso.login.sr3.pcf.xxx.com/userinfo
     services : 
     - serviceName
```

Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
          
            services.AddSession();
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddMvc();
            services.Configure<MyOptions>(myOptions =>
            {
                myOptions.ConnString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            });
            services
           .AddMvc()
           .AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
            services.AddScoped<IRepository, RepositoryConcrete>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddCloudFoundryContainerIdentity(Configuration);

            services.AddAuthentication((options) =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CloudFoundryDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie((options) =>
            {
                options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Home/AccessDenied");
            })
            .AddCloudFoundryOAuth(Configuration);

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;

            });
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            var serviceInfos = CloudFoundryServiceInfoCreator.Instance(Configuration);
           var ssoInfo = serviceInfos.GetServiceInfos<SsoServiceInfo>().FirstOrDefault()
                  ?? throw new NullReferenceException("Service info for an SSO Provider was not found!");

            userInfoEndPoint = ssoInfo.AuthDomain + "/userinfo";
        
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

        }
```

Please help me to know what i am missing or required modification.

Thanking in Advance!

Comment: Is it behind the reverse proxy?

Comment: No @Dreamweaver

Comment: What NuGet packages (and versions) are you using for auth? 
Are you using the SSO tile in PCF?
Has the redirect uri for the app been configured in the SSO system?